# Xamarin Forms and Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader from NuGet Mono.Data.Sqlite misbehaving

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a question about Xamarin Forms C# Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader misbehaving. When compiled to the Android platform the following code works correctly:

```
              SqliteDataReader c = contents.ExecuteReader();
                //Debug.WriteLine("Reading data");

                if (c.HasRows)
                {
                    c.Read();
                    q = new SA_Question(
                        c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_questionguid_text] as string,
                        c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_order_int_primarykey] as long? ?? -100,
                        c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_json_text] as string,
                        c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_finalresponseid_int] as long? ?? -100,
                        c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_final_response_str] as string,
                        Convert.ToInt16(c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_answered_intbool] as string),
                        Convert.ToInt16(c[SA_AWSConstants.tq_uploaded_intbool] as string)
                        );
                }
                c.Close();
```

However, the data returned is inappropriately null if I do:
- "as string" and "Convert.ToInt64" for the "as long? ?? -100" values
- "as int? ?? -100" for the "Convert.ToInt16 .. as string" values

Can anyone explain this behavior?  Manual inspection of the underlying SQLite database reveals presence of appropriate data.

Mono.Data.Sqlite.Portable NuGet 1.0.3.5 (latest stable) with Xamarin Forms 2.2.0.31 (latest stable).

Comment: You say: when its compiled to android, its working correctly. In wich case isn't it working correctly? Xamarin Forms under Android?

Comment: Sorry, by Android I meant Xamarin Forms Android.  The code block itself works, it is the cases listed after where it doesnt.